Matching socks (probability)
Bob has ten pairs of socks, which vary in ten different shades of color, from medium gray (1) to black (10).
When he has worn them all, he washes and dries them all together; unfortunately in the laundry room the light is poor and all the socks there appear black, so they are paired at random.
A pair of socks is unacceptable to wear if the color difference between the two socks is greater than one shade.
What is the probability that the socks will be paired such that all ten pairs are acceptable?
My solution attempt:
Once we have the socks paired together (not necessarily matching), we can always pick one sock per each pair and form the beginning of the natural numbers sequence, starting from zero.
With 10 socks, we can form the sequence 0, 1, 2, ..., 9.
Then we consider the other sock from each pair, and we should realize we can form all the $10!$ permutations.
Some of the permutations will be:
(0,3), (1,9), (2,7), ..., (9,5)
(0,1), (1,7), (2,4), ..., (9,9)
etc...
I think we agree that at the denominator of the probability fraction there is $10!$
Now we should think about the numerator of the fraction, so that the number of acceptable socks pairs.
An algorithm that forms all the acceptable sequences works as follow.
We consider the second element in the parenthesis above, as the first element is naturally ordered.
And furthermore we consider the perfectly matching sequence, that is
(0,0), (1,1), (2,2), ..., (9,9).
So we take the second element and we write all the numbers as a row.
0123456789
We may swap the first 2 figures of the sequence and end up with
1023456789
Can I swap the 2nd and 3rd ?
No, because otherwise I'd end up with
1203456789
but the sequence is not acceptable, because the 0 is in the 2nd position, $2-0=2$, but the figure-position difference must be maximum 1 to be acceptable.
So we should soon realize that if we make a swap, then we have to skip a swap.
If we write a swap with a 1 and no swap with a 0, we could write down the sequence of swaps. With 10 figures, we may at maximum perform 9 swaps (not always leading to an acceptable sequence).
For instance:
101001001
is a swap sequence that leads to an acceptable socks matching, since there are no 1s side by side, that is no swaps one right after the other.
110000000
leads to the sequence 1203456789, which is not acceptable, and in fact there are two 1s side by side.
Now, we consider how many acceptable swaps sequences there are.
A quick inspection leads to the Fibonacci sequence.
Let's write down the first sequences and the last ones:
000000000
000000001
000000010
000000100
000000101
000001000
000001001
000001010
000010000
...
101010100
101010101
We could prove it, but a quick inspection leads to the fact that for $n$ figures, the acceptable swaps sequences are Fibonacci of n+1.
For 10 pairs of socks, we have Fib(11).
My conclusion is that the probability required is
$Fib(11)/10! = 89/10!$
What do you guys think ? Is that correct ?

Can you add your attempt and/or thoughts to the problem?

Sure I can.
I didn't know this is the forum etiquette or custom.
Actually, I already solved it, but the solution is rejected, so what I'd like is to double check with you guys.

Your approach is correct. A briefer explanation is as follows for general number of pairs.
Let $N_n$ be the set of acceptable socks permutations out of $n$ pairs of socks. We order the left sock of each pair in ascending order from $1$ to $n$, where the number represents the shade value. Let $A_n$ and $B_n$ be the sets of all acceptable socks permutations where the $1$st left sock is and is not paired with the $1$st right sock, respectively. Clearly, $N_n=A_n\cup B_n$ and $A_n\cap B_n=\emptyset$. This is because the $1$ left sock is either paired with the $1$st right sock, or it is not, but not both. It is obvious that $|A_n|=|N_{n-1}|$. The reason is that once the $1$st pair of socks has been established, we are left with $n-1$ other pairs of socks. In case of $B_n$, the $1$st left sock is not paired with $1$st right sock. It must be the case that the $1$st left sock is paired with $2$nd right sock and the $1$st right sock is paired with $2$nd left sock. This gives us $|B_n|=|N_{n-2}|$, since when the $1$st and $2$nd pairs of socks have been matched, we are left with $n-2$ other pairs of socks. Finally,
$$
|N_n|=|A_n\cup B_n|=|A_n|+| B_n|=|N_{n-1}|+|N_{n-2}|.
$$
We have $|N_1|=1$ and $|N_2|=2$. Therefore, $|N_n|$ is the famous Fibonacci sequence and the desired probability is $\frac{F_{n+1}}{n!}$ $\blacksquare$

Thank you Mostafa. :)
This is a clean and clear proof of the result I thought.
